# USB Accessories Disabled error: Too much power draw

Tags: ios, usb

When I connect my iPhone cable to MacBookPro it is showing a USB Accessories Disabled error, citing that it is drawing too much power. I have reset SMC, which does not solve the issue. Any help will be appreciated.

[image: Capture of error]

Comment: If SMC reset didn't work and you know your cable is good, you probably need to bring it in for repair.  May be a physical problem.

Comment: This is not a programming question. Please delete this post. It is off-topic here.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Change your cable. Try to use the original cable from Apple. Hopefully this will work, but if not, then you will unfortunately have to go to the Apple store. It should be around 200 to 300 pounds to repair. Respond, if this works and make sure to look around the Internet before going to the shop. I am 99 percent sure that there should be a solution to fix this before going to the Apple store.